# Is Parse indexing array's elements?

Tags: arrays, parse-platform

I have a million users. Each user has a list of favorite books, as an array of strings that are the books IDs. 
I need to search for users that have a specific book in their array "favorite_books_list[]".  Does that mean that the `containedIn` query will be go over a million users, or are the books Ids from all users indexed, so the search is binary  O(log(number of books)) ?

Thanks!

Comment: I expect not indexed, arrays aren't means for large numbers of items

Comment: So, to look for a user that has an element in an array, Parse goes through a million users? That doesn't seem right...

Comment: Since you have a many-to-many relationship between books and users, why arent u using a Parse Relation here? I guess this way parse will handle it better

Comment: You really need to ask parse if you need details, and or test performance